# run javascript after the link of an anchor has opened

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iFrame which contain an anchor with `target="_blank"`. I wish to run some JavaScript in the iFrame after the new window has opened.

I tried using `setTimeout(/*my js to run*/, 0)` in the `onclick` event of the anchor. It works in Chrome but not in Firefox. Putting a 100 ms delay in the setTimeout seems to fix this issue with Firefox, but this solution does not look very clean.

Is there a **standard** way to run js code after a link was opened in a new window?

**edit** some clarifications: the js I want to run triggers a page refresh. If I put it directly in the onclick event, the anchor link is not opened because the onclick event happens before. This is why I need to run the js code after the new window has opened.

**second edit** I have access to the first page and the popup, but not to the target of the link.

Comment: `link was opened` - exact moment you click on link; content on other tab ended loading; just after opening new tab...?

Comment: Do you have access to the page in the popup and is it the same origin as the iFrame and is it the same origin as the parent page? Then use the onload event of the popped page: `window.onload=opener.someFunction;`

Comment: Don't open windows.Also , if the new page which is opened is at your control - you can write code in  document.ready / window.load.

Comment: This sounds more and more like an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - Please tell us what you REALLY want. perhaps not necessary to use JS or popups or such

Comment: @mplungjan I clarified my question a bit

Comment: have a look here http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage

Answer (score 1):

If you need to refresh AND open a link in a new window you do want setTimeout like this

Inline:

```
<a href="popup.html" target="_blank" 
onclick="setTimeout(function() { location.reload(1);},10)">Click</a>
```

Better:

```
<a href="popup.html" id="pop" target="_blank">Click</a>
```

using

```
function reload() {
  setTimeout(function() { location.reload(1);},10);
}
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementbyId("pop").onclick=reload;
}
```

---

Do you have access to the page in the popup and is it the same origin as the iFrame and is it the same origin as the parent page? Then you can use the onload event of the popped page:

```
window.onload=function() { opener.reload(1); }
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I don't really understand why this works and not with `setTimeout(function() { location.reload(1);},0);`. Also I have tested that and firefox chrome and ie8. Is this method really standard?

Comment: I don't have access to the link target page, but I will test that also. Thanks!

Comment: If you do not have access to the other page then you cannot add it I assume. Standard-Schmandard - if it works for you it is...

Answer (score 0):

Add an onReady or onLoad hook into the page that's loading. Then, "after the new window has opened" the JavaScript will be run. If you need to affect the parent window then use `window.opener` in the JavaScript in the popup.